# How to deal with data that expires every day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, worker

I'm creating a rails app and I have a question.
I have data stored in a table that represents user limits on the system: how many times user answer a question (10 per day) for example.

```
id - count - user_id
1      3       1
--------------------
2      5       2
--------------------
3      10      3
```

So I need to reset the count column every day at midnight.
Is there a way I do not need to user a worker to run every day ?

Comment: no. I don't need a simple validation. I need to update the column with the counter and reset every nigh. thanks.

Comment: you can use a background job, which will execute every day and update the column on specific time duration

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many solutions to this problem, so you'd have to decide what is acceptable for your needed.

Regardless of your solution, I strongly recommend saving the Timestamp for each user answer.

Anyway, instead of storing *count*, you could use the Timestamp to derive the count as needed.  But perhaps deriving this value each time might be too inefficient for you.

If you want to store this information, the *count* value is effectively a cache for this computation, and based on the usage you described, count is only relevant for a given day.

So adding little metadata might do the trick

```
|DATE    | ID | COUNT | USER_ID |
|20181124| 1  | 3     | 1       |
```

And access the count for a date and purge the data as needed, or keep indefinitely.

Comment: but I need to reset the count column every day. I think I can to that just updating the count column if it's a new answer in a new day

Comment: Only reading the value for today's date effectively invalidates the other data. Since you can easily build the invariant that `count` is only valid for a specific date/time into your app, you should do so.  Think about how your program will scale and how you can test this condition.  Also keep in mind that midnight data processing is not instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clockwork](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork) and write a method in you're model to update the counter.

place this in /lib/clock.rb in your rails app

```
require 'clockwork'
require_relative '../config/boot'
require_relative '../config/environment'

include Clockwork

every(1.day, 'Update Counter', at: '00:00') do
  User.update_counter
end
```

and in app/models/user.rb:

```
def self.update_counter
  User.all.each { |user| user.update!(counter: 0)}
end
```